# How to implement a good timer in Phaser JS

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, timer, phaser-framework

Hi I'm currently working on a timer for my app that I will port to android phones using phonegap its about a ball game with 10 second timer

Currently im using timer++ increments

```
createLevel: function(lvl) {
    // create levels manually
    // TODO: import from level editor
    switch(lvl) {
        case 1: {
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create((320-128)/2, (480-32)/2, 'element-w').body.immovable = true;

            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here
            break;
        }
        case 6:{
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here

        break;
        }
        case 7:{
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here
        break;
        }

        case 8:
        {
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here
        break;
        }
        case 9:
        {   
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here
        break;
        }
        case 10:
        {
            timer2 = 11;
            walls.create code here
        break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
},
updateCounter: function() {
    timer++;
    timer2--;
    timerText.content = "Time: "+timer2;
    totalTimeText.content = "Total time: "+(totalTimer+timer);
    if(timer2==-1)
    {
        //this.game.add.text(320/3, 480/2, "GAMEOVER", { font: "36px Cambria", fill: "#ffff00" });
        this.game.paused =! this.game.paused;

        this.buttonContinue = this.add.button(0, 0, 'gameover', this.mainM, this);
        totalTimer=0;
        timer=-2;
        level=1;
        //this.buttonContinue = this.add.button(0, 0, 'screen-howtoplay', this.game.state.start('MainMenu');, this);
    }
```

im using timer to add to total timer and timer2 to set the actual timer to 11 before the game ends

however when the game lags the timer go so incredible fast ruining my game
so how do i implement in in such a way that even when the device lags the timer is still functioning properly?

Comment: Make sure your timer doesn't depend on the frame rate. I'm not sure when/where you're calling updateCounter, but if you're expecting it to get called at a certain frequency, you'll run into trouble. 

In modern web browsers, you have access to `window.performance.now()`, which is a very accurate millisecond clock, and it is not dependent on the frame rate. I think you can also use it in phonegap, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your timer is done not by timing events, but rather manipulated by the update function. This means that it is affected by the frame rate. I would suggest doing something like this:

`game.time.events.add(/*time in ms*/, /*func to be called after timer ends*/, this);`